# Why doesn't my procedure work?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, if-statement

I can't figure out why :(

I have to update the table products when I call the the procedure with the parameters(reference_requested, quantity_requested) and "return" (I don't how to do it, i read about return and params in, out and inout, but i didn't understand very well) the value of units sold

```
delimiter &&
create procedure compra (@reference_requested varchar, @quantity_requested int)
begin
  if quantity >= quantity_requested then
    update products
    set quantity = quantity - quantity_requested
    where reference_requested = reference;
    return quantity_requested;
  else
    return quantity;
    update products
    set quantity = 0;
    where reference_requested = reference;
  end if;
end
&&
```

Comment: Where are you setting the initial value for `quantity`?

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: Sintax error in params

Comment: quantity is a field in a table called products, I inserted some data there, it's supossed to compare that data with the params

Comment: Only stored functions can return values - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: As was pointed out in the comments, you cannot return a value (or use a return statement) in a procedure. If you're looking to do that, then you should use "create function" and not "create procedure" and additionally specify a return data type.

In your "else" the "return quantity" statement should be last, right before "end if" or the update will not run.

Comment: Stored procedures do not have a `RETURN` statement, only stored functions.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I just noticed the logical error. I was trying to run this in sqlfiddle and couldn't get it to compile in any case, but I wasn't able to definitively identify what DB and version this was for. More of a Postgres/Oracle guy in general, and from my oracle days found procedures more of a nuisance than anything and basically stopped writing them in favor of functions. Sorry for missing the obvious.

Answer (score 0):

- It is important to indicate the difference between [9.4. User-Defined
  Variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/user-variables.html) (@quantity_requested) and routine parameters (quantity_requested) [13.1.15. CREATE PROCEDURE and CREATE FUNCTION Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-procedure.html), are different   variables.

  Try:

```sql
   ...
   create procedure compra(reference_requested varchar(50), quantity_requested int)
   ...
```

- Does the statement:

```sql
   ...
   where reference_requested = reference;
   ...
```

`reference_requested` refers to the parameter or column in the table?. Avoid the names of
   the parameters/variables are equal to the columns of the tables, this can lead
   to problems.

- The [`RETURN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/return.html):

```sql
   ...
   return quantity;
   ...
```

is used in functions for stored procedure is not used.

Answer (score 0):

1. To return a value from a stored procedure use an `OUT` parameter.
2. Besides issues that have been already mentioned you can't just arbitrarily address `quantity` column in `products` table. It should be used in a context of some statement (e.g. `SELECT`).

Now a streamlined version of your procedure might look something like

```sql
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE compra
(
  IN  _ref_requested VARCHAR(32), 
  IN  _qty_requested INT, 
  OUT _result INT
)
BEGIN
  DECLARE qty INT DEFAULT 0;

  SET qty = 
  (
    SELECT quantity
      FROM products
     WHERE reference = _ref_requested
     LIMIT 1
  );

  SET qty = IF(qty > _qty_requested, _qty_requested, qty);

  UPDATE products
     SET quantity = quantity - qty
   WHERE reference = _ref_requested;

  SET _result = qty;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

To be able to get the value of an `OUT` parameter you have to use a user variable

```sql
SET @result = NULL;
CALL compra('REF001', 25, @result);
SELECT @result;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/baa55)** demo

Comment: @user3006912 Did it help? Do you need more help with your question?